# How to invoke another function only when both the callback inside a function is invoked and remaining part of the function is executed?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

My Angular Code

```
getStatus(transferDTO){
  this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO).subscribe(
    this.save()
  );
  /*
  Remaining code here 
  */
  this.save()
}

function save() {
}
```

Now I don't want to call this.save() twice, I want it to be invoked only after the callback is executed as well as remaining code in the method is executed...
Of course, I can get around this problem as follows

```
getStatus(transferDTO){
  /*
  Remaining code here 
  */
  this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO).subscribe(this.save());
}

save(){

}
```

but I don't want to delay the callback method. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Format the code properly, and do you want to call this.save() function when subscribe method completes its reponse?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes and remaining code should be completed too by the time save function is invoked

Comment: You can wrap you dependent code inside if the block it will run once you had required data

Comment: Can you wrap your remaining code inside the subscribe method of your promise and call the save() method from the same block?

Comment: @ShrutikaPatil ofcourse I can but then again I'll be waiting needlessy for the call back to be invoked inorder to execute some independent code

Answer (score 0):

You could abuse the [`startWith()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/startWith) operator to do achieve it. From the docs

> Returns an Observable that emits the items you specify as arguments
>   before it begins to emit items emitted by the source Observable.

Try the following

```js
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

getStatus (transferDTO) {
  this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO)
    .pipe(startWith(0))
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response === 0) {
          // run some independent code
        } else {
          // run dependent code
          this.save()
        }
      },
      error => { // handle error }
    );
}
```

Make sure the value passed to `startWith()` doesn't resemble the actual value returned by the source observable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET` and the "Remaining code" to execute in parallel, and then call `save()` when both complete, you can just wrap your "Remaining code" in an Observable and use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to execute both Observables in parallel.

Something like this:

```
getStatus(transferDTO) {
  const getStatusId$ = this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO);
  const remainingCode$ = this.getRemainingCode();

  forkJoin(
    getStatusId$,
    remainingCode$
  ).subscribe(res => {
    this.save();
  });
}

getRemainingCode(): Observable<null> {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    /*
    Remaining code here 
    */
    subscriber.next();
    subscriber.complete();
  })
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5oahif)